# Can we invoke an apk file into an external android activity

Tags: android, air, package, classpath, apk

I wanted to know whether its possible to call or invoke an apk file from an external android activity button click so that its possible to run this apk run when the button is pressed.. plzzz note that the button is inside a new android project..

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your onclick event of button,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                          Intent intent = new Intent();
                          PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                          intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
                          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                          startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion unfortunately i don't have the package name or source code of the apk file... is there any alternative method to do this.. @BasimSherif

Comment: I thnk there is no other method to do so. anyway, You can get the package name of any app.You wana know?

Comment: open the app in playstore..in webbrowser's url field you can see the package name.It should be like "com.somthng.somthng"